# subprocess.Popen working in Windows but not working in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, asynchronous, subprocess, popen

I'm trying to run two simple independent codes. One, the caller and the other the called.

The caller code is as follows:

```
import subprocess
import sys

counter = 300
p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, r'D:\analytics\upper_is_called_here.py',
                              str(counter)],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
print("P is", p)
out, err = p.communicate()  # This will get you output
```

This works perfectly fine, as the out shows the print statement in the called code:

```
import sys

a = sys.argv[1]
f = open("test.txt", "a")
f.write('Input is: '+str(a)+'\n')
print('Call worked!')
# for i in range(a):
#     print('Number is: ', i)
#     f.write('Number is: '+str(i)+'\n')
#     # time.sleep(2)

f.close()
```

But the same code, when I take out of my Windows system and try to run in Ubuntu, it just doesn't work and the out shows empty (which means it received no print response from the called code), but on the contrary manages to give back a process ID, something like this: *P is <subprocess.Popen object at 0x03075BF0>*.

Did anyone face this problem? How can I solve this?

My Ubuntu flavor is:

- No LSB modules are available.
- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
- Release: 18.04
- Codename:    bionic

Note: I've been through the similar questions but since they lack minimum, reproducible code, they weren't answered properly. Hence, it isn't really a possible duplicate of other Q.

Comment: That script path would not be correct on ubuntu.

Comment: `print("P is", p)` _should_ print `<subprocess.Popen object at 0x03075BF0>` (the object id will vary per call). If it doesn't do that on Windows, python windows has a bug, not ubuntu. It could be that you double click to run the program on windows and wouldn't see the print, but it should happen.

Comment: Since we the print that means `Popen` did execute and you are not using path "D:\analytics\upper_is_called_here.py". Post the script that failed, not the one that works!

Comment: @All, The path issue you're talking about is a basic sanity check, that I obviously set separately for Ubuntu. How can the Windows path work on Ubuntu. That is done. And object ID differs every time and it makes sense - so, no bug I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The path to your Python file is a Windows path. You should `os.path.join` to create paths instead

```
import os
import subprocess
import sys

if sys.platform == "win32":
    path = os.path.join("D:/", "analytics", "upper_is_called_here.py")
elif sys.platform == "linux"
    path = os.path.join(os.getenv("HOME"), "analytics", "upper_is_called_here.py")

p = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, path,
                          str(counter)],
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Note that you might have to change the Linux path a little bit since I don't know where you placed your file in your Ubuntu system

Comment: True enough, but since OP is seeing _P is <subprocess.Popen object at 0x03075BF0>_, the code ran, meaning that OP did change the path.